# Cannot "ssh -T git@github.com" nor ping external sites

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, git, github

I have the necessity to work with a Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine for some other years as I wrote some software for my studies for that version of Ubuntu.
Possibly for some update, I cannot use git and github (browsing the internet is possible) for that version.
I am using Oracle virtualbox (6.1) and a server (HP proliant ML 350P) to run VMs.
Yesterday, I reset the (Vodafone UK) router, and for a few minutes the system worked.
There are no rules in the firewall of the router that prevents the connection to GitHub and git and github work for the Ubuntu 20.04.
Are there people that had a similar problem and solved the problem?
Thanks

Comment: You need to include more information about the configuration of the system to get any good answers. How is the networking configured? Are you using NAT? How is the rest of your network configured? How is your host configured?

Comment: @vidarlo You are right, I am using bridged connections. I think I solved though, the router blocks connection on 22 so I used ssh over https (443) as you can read from the answer. That worked.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
 Host github.com
 Hostname ssh.github.com
 Port 443
```

to `~/.ssh/config` solved the problem